# Tomcat 9 HTTP2 connector having problems sending byte array with ResponseEntity

Tags: tomcat, http2

I've spent the day fighting this very strange issue. Here is my very simple controller method:

```
    @GetMapping("/bigfile") 
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> big() {
    final byte[] someBytes = new byte[10 * 1000 * 1000];
    LOG.info("I want to write: " + someBytes.length + " bytes");
    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentLength(someBytes.length);
    httpHeaders.setContentType(IMAGE_PNG);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(someBytes, httpHeaders, OK);
}
```

Very basic stuff. It's sending 10mb of zero bytes as a PNG. This should "just work" easily. (Obviously it's not a valid PNG images. My purpose is to send a long byte array as an example.) And it does. It works perfectly.

Until I switch Tomcat to use HTTP/2 by putting:

```
<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"                                              
                   keepAliveTimeout="20000"/>
```

in my host config. Then it starts cutting off the connection after generally about 1mb to 3mb of transfer and I see errors like:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:333) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.appendByteArray(OutputBuffer.java:728) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:657) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:368) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:346) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at     org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:639) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at     org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:639) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.transferTo(InputStream.java:522) ~[na:na]
```

It's driving me crazy. Easy solution is to just not use HTTP/2, which is probably the solution I need to use. Any explanations? Am I missing something, or is this a bug in Tomcat's HTTP/2? For real production use, this confirms to me I shouldn't use Tomcat as the actual front end, but rather I should use Nginx and proxy that to Tomcat. But I had hoped to put that off until later.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I don't know what keepAliveTimeout was doing in there, but I took it out, and then tested again and it worked. I then increased the size of the byte array to 100mb and it worked. I'll leave this answer up here for anyone else who runs into this situation. I still believe it's better to use Nginx as a front-end for real deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error with the `Http2Protocol` at the moment. When uploading data to the servlet, the connection is closed in the middle. When I return a byte array, Chrome sometimes returns the message `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` and most of the time it works. This only happens occasionally, but is more than annoying in productive use.

It also only helped me to remove `HTTP/2` from the config, `keepAliveTimeout` was not set by default.

- I use Tomcat version 9.0.40
- I would also be interested to know if this is a bug in Tomcat or a misconfiguration on my part.